Some equality with symmetric polynomials
I would like to prove an equality using symmetric polynomials defined as  $s_d(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_K)=\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<...<i_d\le K}^{K}\lambda_{i_1}\lambda_{i_2}...\lambda_{i_d}$.
The equality is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{1}{\lambda_k\prod_{i=1,i\neq k}^{K}(\lambda_k-\lambda_i)}s_{d}(\lambda_1,...,\hat{\lambda}_{k},...,\lambda_K)=(-1)^{K-1}\frac{s_d(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_K)}{\prod_{i=1}^{K}\lambda_i}$$
with $\hat{\lambda}_{k}$ representing the lack of $\lambda_k$ in the variables.
With convention $s_{0}=1$, I prove the equality for $d=0$.
Thanks.

Consider the function
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z} \prod_{q=1}^K \frac{1}{z-\lambda_q}
[u^d] \frac{1}{1+uz} \prod_{q=1}^K (1+u\lambda_q).$$
It has the property that
$$\;\underset{z=\lambda_p}{\mathrm{res}}\; f(z)
= \frac{1}{\lambda_p}
\prod_{q=1, q\ne p} \frac{1}{\lambda_p-\lambda_q}
[u^d] \prod_{q=1, q\ne p}^K (1+u\lambda_q).$$
Hence the sum over the residues at $z=\lambda_p$ gives precisely the LHS
as proposed. The residue at infinity is zero and residues sum to zero
so we can evaluate using minus the residues at $z=0$ and at $z=-1/u.$
We get for the former
$$- (-1)^K \prod_{q=1}^K \frac{1}{\lambda_q}
[u^d] \prod_{q=1}^K (1+u\lambda_q).$$
This is precisely the claim. It remains to evaluate the residue at
$z=-1/u$ starting with
$$[u^{d+1}] \frac{1}{z} \prod_{q=1}^K \frac{1}{z-\lambda_q}
\frac{1}{z+1/u} \prod_{q=1}^K (1+u\lambda_q).$$
we find
$$[u^{d+1}] u (-1)^K \prod_{q=1}^K \frac{1}{1/u+\lambda_q}
\prod_{q=1}^K (1+u\lambda_q)
\\ = (-1)^K [u^{d+1}] u^{K+1} \prod_{q=1}^K \frac{1}{1+u\lambda_q}
\prod_{q=1}^K (1+u\lambda_q)
= (-1)^K [u^{d+1}] u^{K+1}.$$
This is zero when $d\lt K$ which confirms the claim because the only
contribution is the one from $z=0.$ We get  $(-1)^K+(-1)^{K+1}=0$ when
$d=K.$
Here we have made repeated use of the formula
$$s_d(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_K) = [u^d] \prod_{q=1}^K
(1+u\lambda_q).$$
